# Iterating Through a Table in Selenium Very Slow

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium python script that reads a table on a page. The table has 3 columns, the first is a list of IDs and the 3rd is a check box. I iterate through the IDs until I find the one I want then then click the corresponding check box and save. It works fine but is very slow as the table can be 4K rows. 
This is the current code (self.questionID is a dictionary with the IDs I'm looking for):

```
k, v in self.questionID.items():
foundQuestion = False
i = 1
while foundQuestion is False:
    questionIndex = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/fieldset[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody[%d]/tr/td[1]' % i).text
    if  questionIndex.strip() == k:
        d = i - 1
        driver.find_element_by_name('selectionIndex[%d]' % d).click()
        foundQuestion = True
    i +=1
```

This is a sample of the table, just the first couple of rows:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="first" width="5%">ID</th>
    <th width="90%">Question</th>
    <th class="last" width="1%">&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="rowodd">AG001&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="rowodd">Foo:&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="rowodd"><input class="input" name="selectionIndex[0]" tabindex="30" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="roweven">AG002&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="roweven">Bar&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="roweven"><input class="input" name="selectionIndex[1]" tabindex="30" type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

As you can probably guess I'm no python ninja. Is there is a quicker way to read this table and locate the correct row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the relevant checkbox *in one go* by using an xpath expression to search a question node by text and to get it's `td` following sibling and `input` inside it:

```
checkbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr/td[1][(@class="rowodd" or @class="roweven") and text() = "%s${nbsp}"]/following-sibling::td[2]/input[starts-with(@name, "selectionIndex")]' % k)
checkbox.click()
```

Note that it would throw [`NoSuchElementException`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException) in case a question and a related to it checkbox is not found. You probably need to catch the exception:

```
try:
    checkbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//tr/td[1][(@class="rowodd" or @class="roweven") and text() = "%s${nbsp}"]/following-sibling::td[2]/input[starts-with(@name, "selectionIndex")]' % k)
    checkbox.click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    # question not found - need to handle it, or just move on?
    pass
```

Comment: I can't get the xpath expression to return anything. The snippet of HTML code I pasted is part of a bigger page. This is the Xpath to return the whole table `/html/body/div[1]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/fieldset[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table`

Comment: @user2565150 ok, the idea though stays the same. Could u share the url you are running it against? Thanks

Comment: The page is part on an enterprise system so I can't post a url. This is paste of the page source: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a83dcc324ea0b3370b3d

Comment: @user2565150 thanks for that, I've improved the xpath, please check if it works for you.

Comment: Cracked it. With your help and a little modifying after reading a load of other xpath stack posts the final version is checkBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div[1]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/fieldset[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td[(@class="rowodd" or @class="roweven") and text()[contains(.,"%s")]]/following-sibling::td[2]/input[starts-with(@name, "selectionIndex")]' % k)